# Error return value, Nodejs, JWT

Tags: node.js, return-value, jwt

```
function isTokened(data) {
    var token = data;
    if(token != null || token != undefined){
        jwt.verify(token, app.get('userToken'), function(err, decoded) {        
            return {
                "user": decoded._doc.name,  
                "href": "/salir",
                "text": "Salir"
            };
        });
    }else{
        return {
            href: "/entrar",
            text: "Entrar"  
        };
    }
}
```

1. TypeError: c:\Users\Hector\Desktop\Proyecto\views\index.jade:81
   79|                 li     80|
   a.text(href='/acerca') Acerca

   > 81|                 if au.user     82|                   li     83|                     a.text(href="/area") #{au.user}     84|
   >   li 
   >          Cannot read property 'user' of undefined    at eval (eval at    
   >   (c:\Users\Hector\Desktop\Proyecto\node_modules\jade\lib\index.js:218:8),
   >   :354:8)    at eval (eval at 
   >   (c:\Users\Hector\Desktop\Proyecto\node_modules\jade\lib\index.js:218:8),
   >   :453:22)    at exports.compile.res
   >   (c:\Users\Hector\Desktop\Proyecto\node_modules\jade\lib\index.js:219:38)
   >   at Object.exports.renderFile
   >   (c:\Users\Hector\Desktop\Proyecto\node_modules\jade\lib\index.js:380:38)
   >   at Object.exports.renderFile
   >   (c:\Users\Hector\Desktop\Proyecto\node_modules\jade\lib\index.js:370:21)
   >   at View.exports.__express [as engine]
   >   (c:\Users\Hector\Desktop\Proyecto\node_modules\jade\lib\index.js:417:11)
   >   at View.render
   >   (c:\Users\Hector\Desktop\Proyecto\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:126:8)
   >   at tryRender
   >   (c:\Users\Hector\Desktop\Proyecto\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:639:10)
   >   at EventEmitter.render
   >   (c:\Users\Hector\Desktop\Proyecto\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:591:3)
   >   at ServerResponse.render
   >   (c:\Users\Hector\Desktop\Proyecto\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:961:7)
   >   at c:\Users\Hector\Desktop\Proyecto\app.js:167:6    at Layer.handle 
   >   [as handle_request]
   >   (c:\Users\Hector\Desktop\Proyecto\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
   >   at next
   >   (c:\Users\Hector\Desktop\Proyecto\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
   >   at Route.dispatch
   >   (c:\Users\Hector\Desktop\Proyecto\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
   >   at Layer.handle [as handle_request]
   >   (c:\Users\Hector\Desktop\Proyecto\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
   >   at
   >   c:\Users\Hector\Desktop\Proyecto\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:277:22

Answer (score 1):

jwt.verify is not a sync function so your function ends up exiting without returning anything. You need to use callback approach to get verify result. You want something like this:

```
function isTokened(data, callback) {
    if(data){
        jwt.verify(data, app.get('userToken'), function(err, decoded) {        
            callback && callback({
                "user": decoded._doc.name,  
                "href": "/salir",
                "text": "Salir"
            });
        });
    }else{
        callback && callback({
            href: "/entrar",
            text: "Entrar"  
        });
    }
}
```

You will probably want to do some error handling in case jwt.verify returns an error or decoded does not contain required fields.